# get all session from one suffix in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, session

i want to create a shop site by laravel. now i want create cart page in my site.

i want to create a session for every one product that user want to shop it.

and showing them in cart page

all information from product saving in a array. and i create a session with this array values.

array and session like this

```php
        $data = [
        'product' => $request->input('product'),
        'quantity' => 1,
        'price' => $request->input('price')
        ];

        $request->session()->put('cart_'. $request->input('product_id') , $data);
```

you can see i create a session for every product that user select on and session name is the cart_(product id)

now i want to showing all session with (cart_) suffix in cart page.

but i dont know how i can to show every session with the different name and one suffix.

for example

user want to shop three product

i create three session with the different name but one suffix

and i want to showing all product that user select them in cart page

the sessions

```php
        $data = [
        'product' => product test,
        'quantity' => 1,
        'price' => 300
        ];

        $request->session()->put('cart_433' , $data);

// -------------------

        $data = [
        'product' => product test2,
        'quantity' => 1,
        'price' => 600
        ];

        $request->session()->put('cart_10' , $data);
// -----------------------

        $data = [
        'product' => product test3,
        'quantity' => 1,
        'price' => 200
        ];

        $request->session()->put('cart_54' , $data);
```

i want to showing like this

```html
<p>product test<p>
<p>300</p>
<hr>

<p>product test2<p>
<p>600</p>
<hr>

<p>product test3<p>
<p>200</p>

<hr><hr>
<p>1100</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put all the products of cart under a single variable of session.

**Understand difference between *Session::put* and *Session::push*.
*Session::push* appends to existing data and *Session::put* removes existing data and updates.**

```
$data = array(
        "product" => 1,
        "quantity" => 1,
        "price" => 1
        );

Session::push('cart', $data); //inserting 1st item

$data = array(
   "product" => 2,
   "quantity" => 2,
   "price" => 2
   );

Session::push('cart', $data); //inserting 2nd item

$data= array(
    "product" => 3,
    "quantity" => 3,
    "price" => 3
    );

Session::push('cart', $data);//inserting 3rd item
```

And then you will get output of Session as

```
//dd(Session::get('cart'));
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "product" => 1
    "quantity" => 1
    "price" => 1
  ]
 1 => array:3 [▼
   "product" => 2
   "quantity" => 2
   "price" => 2
 ]
 2 => array:3 [▼
   "product" => 3
   "quantity" => 3
   "price" => 3
 ]
]
```

Then you can loop into `Session::get('cart')` and publish result as you want

> just for reference

```
foreach(Session::get('cart') as $item)
{
    dump($item['product']);
    dump($item['quantity']);
    dump($item['price']);
}
```